# A multivariable function that is not differentiable only at $(-1<x<1, y=0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have to think of a function with two variables($f: R^2 \rightarrow R)$ that is continuous at every points in $R^2$ but not differentiable only at $B= \{ (x,y)|-1<x<1, y=0 \}$.

At first I came up with this function:
$$
f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2},& x<-1\\\\ |y|,&-1\le x \le 1 \\\\ \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},&x>1 \end{cases}
$$
But I realized that this function is not differentiable in points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ which are not included in $B$. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: *Hint*: flatten the $\lvert y\rvert$ as you move towards $x=\pm 1$ and let $f=0$ outside $\lvert x\rvert<1$.

Comment: @user10354138 Wow Thank you!!